# Mongodb dont update document using Mongoskin and Hapi

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, hapi.js, mongoskin

Created a server in HAPI and mongoskin, the problem is that the server does not update the documents in the collection.

I've tried many ways, I am following the alias documentation hapi and mongoskin, but still without success.

SERVER PUT:

```
{
        method: 'PUT',
        path: '/{collectionName}/{id}',
        handler: function(req, reply){
            loadCollection(req.params.collectionName,
                function(collection){
                    collection.updateById(
                        {_id: id(req.params.id)},
                        {$set: req.payload},
                        {safe: true, multi:false},
                        function(e, result){
                            if (e) return reply(e)
                            reply((result === 1) ? {msg: 'success', result: result} : {msg: 'error', result: result})
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

ANGULAR CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.item.put().then(function(res){
    //$scope.item._etag.$oid = res._etag;
    //$scope.loadItem();
    toast.msgToast($scope.section+ ' #' +$scope.item._id+ ' ....Atualizado!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$http` from your Angular controller to call your server put method:

```
$http.put('/thecollectioname/' + $scope.item._id, $scope.item).success(function () {
   toast.msgToast($scope.section+ ' #' +$scope.item._id+ ' ....Atualizado!');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I already had a function with htttp and gave the same problem , test just put your , the error is the same: {"msg" : "error" , "result" : 0}

Comment: That's not an error, you aren't getting any result for the query but everything works fine. Check the query you are doing, check if the ID is correct, etc...

Comment: Then , but not this recording the update in the mongo.